# Ubuntu Server automaticly connect to VPN at boot

Tags: networking, server, vpn

I need to set up a server out in the field. The power and network conditions are not very good. The location is unmanned. 
I need the server to connect to a vpn every time it boots or re-connects to the network. This should be done automaticly as there is no one at the location to logon. 
Is this possible?

Thanks.

Br. Simon

Comment: What you use to connect `vpn` and  through witch interface?

Comment: I will use the ethernet cable interface eth0. I don't know who to connect to a vpn at all from the cli. So what network manager i need and so on I need help with as well.

Answer (score 0):

Create `NM` connection to `vpn`. Supply all params.

Then create script witch will be executed when interface `eth0` go up.

Create script for `eth0` interface

```
sudo nano /etc/network/if-up.d/script
```

put in script this

```
# Check for specific interface if desired
[ "$IFACE" != "eth0" ] || exit 0
# trigger vpn connection
nmcli con up id ConnectionName
```

Save and exit.

Make script called script with execute permissions 755

```
sudo chmod 755 /etc/network/if-up.d/script
```

Explanation

When server go up or reconnect, server will see that and will be trigger nmcli command. Your server will be connected to vpn server